# Simple functions and mesurabilty

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have the question to the following:

Let $(X, \mathcal{A})$ be a mesrurable space and $f: X \rightarrow [0,\infty]$. Show that f is measurable iff there are $a_n \in [0,\infty]$ and $A_n\in \mathcal{A}$ sucht that $f=\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n 1_{A_n}$.

So far, I've proved the claim for simple functions $f=\sum_{n=1}^N a_n 1_{A_n}$. Is this enough, if I use then the MCT in the end?

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**
To show that $f$ is measurable if $f = \sum_{n \geq 1} a_n \mathbf{1}_{A_n}$, note that $f = \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^k a_n \mathbf{1}_{A_n}$. One can show in general that a pointwise limit of measurable functions is again measurable. This also follows from the monotone convergence theorem, which also gives you that $$\int \sum_{n \geq 1} a_n \mathbf{1}_{A_n} = \lim_{k \to \infty} \int \sum_{n=1}^k a_n \mathbf{1}_{A_n} d\mu.$$

For the other direction, you have to show that any measurable function $f$ admits a representation in the form $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n \mathbf{1}{A_n}$. Note that it suffices to find a representation $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a_n \mathbf{1}_{A_n}$. Now let $a_n = 2^n$ and let $A_n$ consist of those $x \in X$ for which $f(x)$ has a $1$ in the $n$-th place in its binary expansion. Then all that is left is to show that the set $A_n$ is measurable.

Comment: This does not completely work (although the idea is correct), since $f$ is allowed to take the value $\infty$.